# How does Cassandra handle insufficient disk space?

Tags: cassandra

I would like to know how Cassandra cluster handles members with insufficient disk space.

I have read that it probably lets them go down with error but that was while back.

If this is still true is there any sensible way to prevent them from draining the whole disk without downtime, for example to turn them to read only mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra has four ways of handing this scenario.  You can configure this behavior with the `disk_failure_policy` property in the `cassandra.yaml`.  The default is:

```
disk_failure_policy: stop
```

`stop` Disables gossip and client connections to the node, but leaves it running.  This allows it to be analyzed via JMX-based tools.

The other options are:

- `die` Stops the Cassandra process for file system errors.
- `stop_paranoid` Stops the Cassandra process for SSTable errors, and errors on startup.
- `best_effort` Cassandra will try to respond to requests based on the remaining SSTables that it *can* get at, but will no longer use the full/failed disk.
- `ignore` Essentially, requests that can be served are served, and requests that fail, are allowed to fail.

For what you're talking about, `ignore` would probably work.

In theory, this scenario shouldn't result in downtime.  Your other nodes should be able to pick up the slack and allow you to fix the full node at your earliest convenience.  If this is only a single-node cluster, then there really isn't a way around downtime for fixing a failed disk or attaching additional storage.